# open the new activity from function

Tags: android

I want to open the new activity in function. Can I open if already in `oncreate()` method the  `setcontext(R.layout.main)` is there.

How can we open later in function new screen or activity?

Answer (score 2):

Simply call

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity.this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Your `NewActivity.class` must be define in your `androidmanifest.xml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the community.

It looks like you are not familiar with the very basics of android. Please start reading the [official developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) especially the [Activity section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html)